# Java ANSI и UTF-8 проблемы с компиляцией

Tags: java, utf-8

Столкнулся с проблемой, написав программу Java на Windows (кодировка ANSI) перенес исходники на Linux(Ubuntu) там в исходнике все названия кнопок которые были написаны на кириллице превратились в крякозябры, подсказали что нужно сохранить документ в кодировке UTF-8, действительно кириллица отображалась правильно, но исходники не поддавались компиляции, выводилась ошибка:

```
Tabl.java:1: error: illegal character: \187
я╗┐import javax.swing.JFrame;
 ^
1 error
```

читал что при компиляции можно использовать команду "-encoding"
но не знаю как её правильно использовать, и нужно ли её использовать, посоветуйте как легче справится с проблемой. Спасибо.

Comment: в каком IDE писали на винде и сохранились ли исходники на самой винде?  
Как вариант - открыть исходники в убунте и изменять всё ручками

Comment: я только в блокноте и пишу, IDE не пользуюсь на этапе обучения.

Comment: Ну вообще-то

     -encoding encoding
                Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If -encoding is not specified, the platform default converter is used.

Но если кодировка была ANSI -- то откуда кириллица? (скорее всего cp1251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел, в файл при сохранении в формате отличном от системного (по умолчанию) добавлялся BOM (Byte Order Mask)

[Википедия Юникод](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Юникод)

> Для определения формата представления
> Юникода в начало текстового файла
> записывается сигнатура — символ U+FEFF
> (неразрывный пробел с нулевой
> шириной), также именуемый меткой
> порядка байтов (англ. byte order mark,
> BOM). Это позволяет различать UTF-16LE
> и UTF-16BE, поскольку символа U+FFFE
> не существует. Также этот способ
> иногда применяется для обозначения
> формата UTF-8, хотя к этому формату и
> неприменимо понятие порядка байтов.
> Файлы, следующие этому соглашению,
> начинаются с таких последовательностей
> байтов:
>
> UTF-8  EF BB BF
>
> UTF-16BE  FE FF
>
> UTF-16LE  FF FE
>
> UTF-32BE  00 00 FE FF
>
> UTF-32LE  FF FE 00 00

в некоторых текстовых редакторах есть функция "кодировка UTF-8 без BOM", после сохранения в таком виде всё компилировалось корректно.

Answer (score 0):

[параметры для javac](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/howto/java/encoding.html)

хотя я лично пробовал игратся с кодировкой и у меня не получилось скомпилировать простенький класс :)

с другой стороны вы можете избежать излишних трудностей если будете использовать IDE (напр. eclipse) - pure java есть вариант и для linux и для windows